# php excel script getting caught into while loop infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to upload a CSV data to insert into the mysql database. I am getting caught into while infinite loop and printing only the first row of csv file.

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
    <?php 

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test',$conn);

echo ($conn)?'connection estabished': 'not connected';

if($_POST['submit'])
{
$file = $_FILES['f']['tmp_name'];

//var_dump(file($file));
var_dump($file);

$fileop = fopen($file, 'r') or die('uncable to open file ');

$getcsvdata = fgetcsv($fileop, '100', ',');


var_dump($getcsvdata);

while (($getcsvdata) !==false )
{



   echo  $id =              $getcsvdata[0];
   echo  $region =          $getcsvdata[1];
   echo  $skills_category = $getcsvdata[2];
   echo  $date =            $getcsvdata[3];
   echo  $time =            $getcsvdata[4];
   echo  $location =        $getcsvdata[5];
 echo '<br/>';   

    # insert query to run here 
}



fclose($fileop);

}




?>



<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="f" value="upload">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$getcsvdata !==false` is always true.  Because it is == `Array`

Comment: You should really be using mysqli. The mysql functions are terribly out of date. `http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php`

Comment: why don't you follow exactly what this page shows http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#example-2458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgetcsv function has to be inside the while loop condition.

so it has be be like

```
while ($getcsvdata = fgetcsv($fileop, '100', ','))
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

change this

```
while (($getcsvdata) !==false )
```

to

```
while (!($getcsvdata))
```

Comment: Using this loop is only working once. so showing only the first row

Answer (score 0):

To stop when you reach the total number of records change to the following:

```
$i=0;

while ($i<count($getcsvdata))
{
   echo  $id =              $getcsvdata[0];
   ...
   echo  $location =        $getcsvdata[5];
 echo '<br/>';   
   $i++;
    # insert query to run here 
}
```

**** Update ****

You need to go through the rows, not just the fields in a single row.  So, ignoring the first part of the answer change to:

```
while($getcsvdata = fgetcsv($fileop, '100', ',')){
       echo  $id =              $getcsvdata[0];
       echo  $region =          $getcsvdata[1];
       echo  $skills_category = $getcsvdata[2];
       echo  $date =            $getcsvdata[3];
       echo  $time =            $getcsvdata[4];
       echo  $location =        $getcsvdata[5];
       echo "<hr/>";
  }
```

This while statement says "if there is another record to get, then get it and put into an array of fields `$getcsvdata`.

Comment: no while loop is running 6 times and stop, printing on the first row of excel.

Comment: Right after `$i=0;`, if you add `echo count($getcsvdata);`, what is your output?

Comment: I get number 6. Its the same number of cell fields in the first row